# Rails: change render view paths for ONE render call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, actionview, renderpartial

I want to change view paths for `render` call (partial):

```
vp1 = ActionView::PathSet.new
vp1.prefixes << 'bla1'
render partial: 'abc', view_paths: vp1

vp2 = ActionView::PathSet.new
vp2.prefixes << 'bla2'
render partial: 'abc', view_paths: vp2
```

Such as `prepend_view_paths` but for ONE `render`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could add specific paths before render and delete after.

```
self._view_paths.paths << "/home/someone/..."
render(partial: ...)

# after filter
self._view_paths.paths.delete("/home/someone/")
```